# File input reading in C

Tags: c

I am a student learning C programming and I am learning file input. Below is the code. I have data text file to read from. I am confused with what is the meaning of `status` here, the condition in which `(status != 0)` what is the meaning of `0` and use of `return -1`.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *inp;
    int status;
    int a, b, c, d, e;

    status = fopen_s(&inp, "data.txt", "r");

    if (status != 0)
    {
        printf("Error");
        return -1;
    }

    status = fscanf_s(inp, "%d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);`  

    while (status != EOF)
    {
        printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d, e);`
        status = fscanf_s(inp, "%d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format this properly. The easiest way is to paste all your code, select it and hit `ctrl+k`.

Comment: Read the API ref. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx)

Comment: The `fopen_s` function attempts to open the file specified. The function will return an error code of type `errno_t`. If the operation is successful, that error code will be 0. Otherwise it will return an integer specifying the type of error that occured. You can take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am confused with what is the meaning of status here

It's just a variable to keep the return value of `fopen_s()` and later `fscanf_s()`.

> the condition in which `(status != 0)` what is the meaning of `0`

[A manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx) helps: `fopen_s()` returns error codes, or `0` on success. This just checks whether there was an error opening the file.

> and use of `return -1.`

Whatever you return from `main()` is passed as the *exit code* to your operating system. Any value other than `0` means there was an error. See also [`exit()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exit) -- calling exit with a value has the same effect as returning this value from `main()`.

---

Side note: Just use the standard functions (without `_s` suffix). Some of these `_s` functions are specific to Microsoft, others are a bit different on Microsoft compilers than specified by the standard -- just spare yourself the hassle. Using just [`fopen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) and [`fscanf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) (beware of the different signatures!) makes your program immediately portable.